# Non decreasing list of lists

Tags: f#

I've been trying to implement a function that takes a list of integers and then return a list of lists of integers which are non-decreasing. 
i.e

```
let ls = [ 1;2;3;5;6;3;2;5;6;2] 
I should get [[1;2;3;5;6];[3];[2;5;6];[2]]
```

How should i approach this ? i'm a total noob at functional programming.

I can think of the steps needed: 
1. Start a new sublist, compare each element with the one next to it. if it is greater then add to list. if not, start a new list and so on.

From what I've learned so far from the book Functional Programming with f# ( which i just started a few days ago), I could possibly use pattern matching and a recursive function maybe to go through the list comparing two elements
something like this :

```
let rec nonDecreasing list = 
  match list with 
  | (x,y) :: xs when x <= y ->
```

how would I go about to create the sublists using pattern matching ?
or have i approached the question wrongly?

Comment: the approach is correct

Comment: Why are you swallowing the 3 but returning the 2? E.g. should this be: `[[1;2;3;5;6];[3];[2;5;6];[2]]`?

Comment: that was a mistake on my part. You are right

Comment: Edited your Q to reflect the missing 3. Can you put together a reclusive version? Or still stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there's already a solution using `fold`, here's another answer using `foldBack`, so you don't have to reverse it. Now you can backout a pure recursive solution.

```
let splitByInc x lls = // x is an item from the list, lls is a list of lists 
    match lls with
    | y::xs -> // split the list of lists into head and tail
        match y with 
        | h::_ when x <= h ->  (x::y)::xs // take the head, and compare it with x, then cons it together with the rest 
        | _ -> [x]::lls  // in the other case cons the single item with the rest of the list of lists  
    | _ -> [[x]] // nothing else to do, return the whole thing

let ls = [ 1;2;3;5;6;3;2;5;6;3] 
List.foldBack splitByInc ls [] //foldBack needs  a folder function, a list and a starting state
```

**Edit:**

Here's a really simplified example, you could write a recursive sum and compare it with the fold version:

```
let sumList x y =
    x + y
List.foldBack sumList ls 0 //36
```

To better understand what splitByInc does, try it out with these examples:

```
splitByInc 4 [[5;6;7]] // matches (x::y)::xs 
splitByInc 4 [] // matches [[x]] 
splitByInc 4 [[1;2;3]] // matches [x]::lls
```

Comment: Nice, doesn't require the artificial `Int32.MinValue` for initialization either

Comment: that works perfectly! Still trying to figure out how it works though.
What are x and lls? I get they are parameters to the function but I'm afraid I can't understand what

Comment: It's black magiks.... if you build the version without fold it will be all clear. But in very simple terms it splits the list into head and tail, checks for equality and prepends the result if ok. Fold and foldback  abstract away the revulsion, hence they are useful but not when you are trying to learn reversion.

Comment: @YingYangz I added some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

That's basically the same answer as the one given by [@s952163](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39803146/4925216) but maybe more readable by removing the nested match and also more general by adding a comparison function to do the "packing".

```
let packWhile predicate list =
  let folder item = function
  | []                          -> [[ item ]]
  | (subHead :: _ as subList) :: accTail
    when predicate item subHead -> (item :: subList) :: accTail
  | accList                     -> [ item ] :: accList

  List.foldBack folder list []

// usage (you can replace (<=) by (fun x y -> x <= y) if it's clearer for you)
packWhile (<=) [1;2;3;5;6;3;2;5;6;3]

// you can also define a function to bake-in the comparison
let packIncreasing list = packWhile (<=) list
packIncreasing [1;2;3;5;6;3;2;5;6;3]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a `fold`, where your `'State` is a tuple containing the previous value, the list of lists, and the current non-decreasing list you're working on.

```
let ls = [ 1;2;3;5;6;3;2;5;6;3] 
let _, listOfLists, currList =
  ((Int32.MinValue, [], []), ls) ||>
      List.fold(fun (prev, listOfLists, currList) t ->
                  if t < prev then //decreasing, so store your currList and start a new one
                    t, currList::listOfLists, [t]
                  else //just add t to your currList
                    t, listOfLists, t::currList)
let listOfLists = currList::listOfLists //cleanup: append final sublist
let final = List.rev(List.map List.rev listOfLists) //cleanup: reverse everything
printfn "%A" final
```

Note you'll have to clean up, adding the final list to the list-of-lists, and then reversing the full list-of-lists and each sublist once you've done the fold.